# How to run jar files on Computers that does not have java.Can it solve by Coveting jar to .exe,?

Tags: java, mysql, jar, backend

I completed a **Java Project**(with back end MySQL) i clean and build the project.now a **jar** file is obtained.i want to run this jar file on an other computer which does not have java.So the JAR file may not run.How can i solve this problem.? Can it solve by converting the JAR file into **.EXE**? then where i keep project back end(MySQL).? is there any possibility to store the back end as a **txt ** file.?

Comment: embedded database means -> a bunch of code that had methods to work like a SQL Server program (packed to a JAR for easy) that avoids the overhead and need of a full fledged server program running . http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheDerby/article.html .also seatrch for nosql db

Comment: Please do not ask two different questions in one StackOverflow question.

Comment: @RobinGreen Four, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have Java installed to run a jar file, just like you have to have .NET installed to run C# code. You could have your installer install a JVM if necessary ([install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/features.html) does this), or you could compile your program to a native executable (like with [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/)). If you're using MySQL, then your program will have to have access to some MySQL database; if your SQL is sufficiently standard, you could use an embedded database like H2.

A Web site can be hosted from any computer, but if there's no Internet connection, how would anyone connect to it? Java can run a Web server (such as embedded Jetty or Tomcat), but it seems like you really need to learn from the beginning about Java Web applications, which are written in a very different style from GUI applications.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web application, all your code resides in a web server. Clients don't need java, mysql or anyother libraries. But clients need to have an internet connection and a web browser.

Typically you don't deploy web applications in client's computer. But there can be few cases this may be required. In such a case, client's computer need to have JVM, mysql and a web server installed.

If it's really necessary, you can embed a web container like tomcat or jetty in a standalone application. You can also embed a DBMS like mysql or derby. There are many resources available on these subjects on the internet. But in this case, client must have JVM installed.